# How to define a different color and width of an EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, border, android-view

This is how I go about adding a border to a `EditText`. How can I go about adding a border only on 3 sides of a `EditText`, and define a different color and width to each of the borders?

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setText("Find");
editText.setWidth(555);

GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
border.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);  // white background
border.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);  // black border with full
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    editText.setBackgroundDrawable(border);
} else {
    editText.setBackground(border);
}
```

My attempt below doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="22dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#746565" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Vielen dank im voraus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layer-list drawable and define 3 different rectangle shape with custom width and color, and hide 3 side of each shape to show only one side. like this:

`my_edittext_border.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list android:paddingLeft="30dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-3dp"
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#11ee66" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-5dp"
        android:left="-5dp"
        android:top="-5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#0000ff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now set this drawable to your `EditText` background:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_edittext_border"
```

Comment: Thank you @Sisa for your answer. How can I add a padding for the left side? I tried `android:left="12dp"` but this only pushes the left border 12 pixels further inside.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev add padding to layer-list  `android:paddingLeft="30dp"`

Comment: Hi @SiSa. I tried that, but no changes show. Could you please include it in the answer you gave if you can? I'm a complete Android dev newbie.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev I changed my code. Please notice that if you set padding in drawable (like what I did in above code), then you must not set padding to your view in the layout, Otherwise drawable padding will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Set this drawable as background and modify it as per your choice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!--Top border-->
        <item
            android:bottom="-2dp"
            android:left="-2dp"
            android:right="-2dp"
            android:top="0dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/black" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <!--Bottom border-->
        <item
            android:bottom="0dp"
            android:left="-2dp"
            android:right="-2dp"
            android:top="-2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/orange" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <!--Right border-->
        <item
            android:bottom="-2dp"
            android:left="-2dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:top="-2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/remove" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <!--Left border-->
        <item
            android:bottom="-2dp"
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="-2dp"
            android:top="-2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/green" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Thank you @Usman Rana for your answer. How can I add a padding for the left side? I tried android:left="12dp" but this only pushes the left border 12 pixels further inside

Comment: if my answer i have added left border as well, scroll the code down to check that . You need to give value in -ve to hide the border you want

Answer (score 0):

Above all answer you can also use vector drawable to draw that :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="200px"
    android:width="200px"
    android:viewportHeight="150"
    android:viewportWidth="200">
    <path
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/black"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0,0  L100,0 "/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/white"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
       android:pathData="M100,0  L100,100 "/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M100,100  L0,100 "/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M0,100  L0,0 "/>

</vector>
```